# Can anyone tell how to display a PDF file in new browser which is stored in file system using servlets and JSP?

Tags: java, servlets

Can anyone tell me how to display a PDF file in new browser which is stored in file system using servlets and JSP?

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 

     File file = new  File("C:\\Users\\sramya\\Desktop\\bfolder\\2014\\52063.pdf")‌​;
     response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
     response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length())); response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"52063.pdf\""); 
     Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream()); 
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is the pdf is from user machine or it is on your server ?

Comment: user machine path is " C:\Users\sramya\Desktop\\.pdf

Comment: @ramya That is highly impossible. How you are getting that path into your code ? From Database or user selecting file ?

Comment: user selecting file

Comment: protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\sramya\\Desktop\\bfolder\\2014\\52063.pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"52063.pdf\"");
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
    }

    }

Comment: you doing wrong here in servlet. You shouldnt take that path inside servlet

Comment: Ramya, are you just showing the file whatever user selects ?

Comment: yes whatever the user selects then pdf file should display in a new pop window

Comment: But why you given hardcoded path in side servlet request ?

Comment: If you are doing that for testing, that is fine. If you want to push the pdf to browser, just make a stream out if the received pdf and send as PDF stream to browser. Hope that is clear :)

Comment: sorry i didn't get u ... could u please send me the code to select a pdf and display in a new pop window .

Comment: I mean , just read the file into a stream and send that stream to client. It automatically show the pdf in browser.

Comment: actually i want to select a pdf file and  display  pdf file  in adobe reader with mentioned dimensions is there any possibility in java servlet using netbeans ??

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: tq @suresh Atta ... I want to open pdf file in new pop window but window should open in the same browser .